# Using ViewPager, outOfmemomery error when dealing with images

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-image

I have been using viewPager to load images: it workers perfectly for two images, however when I increases the number of images it crashed. 
I have compressed the image sizes but this did not solve the problem. 
According to some questions which are similar on StackOverflow I have also used Recycle but this as well did not solve the problem

any other way to increase memory management ?

thanks

Comment: How did you compress them and how is your adapter setup?

Comment: Would you be interested in using an external library? Picasso is really good. It handles cashing.

Comment: @zgc7009 I compressed them using photo editing application.

Comment: @MirianaItani if i do not have any other choice then I'll try it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you used the sample size to scale them? Try creating the bitmaps with this, so it loads only the size bitmap required rather than the full size into memory.

```
public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = cxt.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int reqWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;

    double devCal2 =  (height*1000)/width;
    int reqHeight = (int) ((devCal2/1000)*reqWidth);

    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}

public Bitmap createBitmap(){

    BitmapFactory.Options options2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options2.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    options2.inDither=true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(cxt.getExternalFilesDir(filepath) +"/companylogo.png",options2);
    options2.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options2);//=32
    options2.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(cxt.getExternalFilesDir(filepath) +"/companylogo.png",options2);
}
```

For reference please check http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

I also read that using weak reference is a good idea for images, maybe this will help http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/07/31/loading-caching-and-displaying-images-in-android-part-1/